# Run as Groovy Script

Tags: groovy-eclipse

After years of working fine, for the last few months I've not had the ability to Run As Groovy Script.
I can select it from the menu, but nothing happens.
Today I installed the latest Eclipse and plugin in an attempt to fix, but no luck.
What went wrong? Is there a log file to check?

https://dist.springsource.org/release/GRECLIPSE/3.8.0/e4.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of the launch is written to the Console view. If there was a problem launching you can check the Error Log view for an entry. The launch configuration under Run > Run Configurations... > Groovy Script may also reveal classpath or other issues.

Comment: In the Error Log it says "src/main/groovy/yada/yada/folder [in (project)] is not on its project's build path"

Comment: I don't think that directory was ever on the build path before, but if the rules have changed I'll have to adapt I guess. However simply adding that directory to the project source path was not enough.

Comment: Are you trying to run a script from a folder that is not part of the project compile set?  Can you provide a small project that recreates the issue?

Comment: When I try to run a script that is not in a project source folder I get "<project root> [in Bugs] is not on its project's build path".  I think this is consistent with what you have reported.  When the launch config is being created, there is a check if the script is located in a "test" folder and so the test libraries of the project should also be included.  I have created an issue ticket for this: https://github.com/groovy/groovy-eclipse/issues/1163